# Getting Null response even the request is successful in Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am getting null in Response body in Retrofit 2. whereas in body i have valid data.

```
 //using retrofit
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

    Retrofit adapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(Config.CUSTOMER_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(httpClient.build())
                        .build();
    RegisterCustomer api = adapter.create(RegisterCustomer.class);
    Call<Model> call = api.registerCustomer(custName.getText().toString() , phoneNumber.getText().toString(), address.getText().toString(), "abc");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, retrofit2.Response<Model> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful())
            {
                Log.d("CallBack",response.body().getCustId()+"###"+response.body().getCustUri()+response.code());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("CallBack","error saving customer"+t.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

My Interface.

```
  public interface RegisterCustomer
{
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("customer")
    Call<Model> registerCustomer(
            @Field("cust_name") String cust_name,
            @Field("phone") String phone,
            @Field("address") String address,
            @Field("apikey") String apikey
    //        Callback<Response> callback
    );
}
```

My logcat is below :

```
01-25 12:52:26.139 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.0.101/grocery_api/customer http/1.1
01-25 12:52:26.139 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
01-25 12:52:26.142 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 57
01-25 12:52:26.142 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: cust_name=deep&phone=6656455465&address=bhdjih&apikey=abc
01-25 12:52:26.142 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: --> END POST (57-byte body)
01-25 12:52:26.529 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: <-- 201 Created http://192.168.0.101/grocery_api/customer (386ms)
01-25 12:52:26.529 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 25 Jan 2017 07:22:29 GMT
01-25 12:52:26.529 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.4
01-25 12:52:26.529 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.4
01-25 12:52:26.529 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 42
01-25 12:52:26.529 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
01-25 12:52:26.529 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
01-25 12:52:26.529 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
01-25 12:52:26.529 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: {"cust_id":18,"cust_uri":"\/customer\/18"}
01-25 12:52:26.529 12163-12525/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (42-byte body)
01-25 12:52:26.533 12163-12163/com.lab.yourhomebasket D/CallBack: null###null201
```

My valid response is {"cust_id":18,"cust_uri":"/customer/18"} I am getting null###null201 also data is saved successfully on server.

Model.java

```
           import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "cust_id",
        "cust_uri"
})
public class Model {

    @JsonProperty("cust_id")
    private Integer custId;
    @JsonProperty("cust_uri")
    private String custUri;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonProperty("cust_id")
    public Integer getCustId() {
        return custId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("cust_id")
    public void setCustId(Integer custId) {
        this.custId = custId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("cust_uri")
    public String getCustUri() {
        return custUri;
    }

    @JsonProperty("cust_uri")
    public void setCustUri(String custUri) {
        this.custUri = custUri;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: add `Model.java` also.

Comment: You have added `GsonConvertorFactory` to your retrofit client but you were using Jackson for json parsing.. You either need to change your model to conform to Gson as specified in the answer below or use the jackson convertor for retrofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check your `Model.java` should be like below.

```
public class Model {

@SerializedName("cust_id")
@Expose
private Integer custId;
@SerializedName("cust_uri")
@Expose
private String custUri;

public Integer getCustId() {
return custId;
}

public void setCustId(Integer custId) {
this.custId = custId;
}

public String getCustUri() {
return custUri;
}

public void setCustUri(String custUri) {
this.custUri = custUri;
}

}
```

Comment: You should specify the reason why this model works as well so that people don't just copy paste but understand why the above code works